# Troubles with sbt compiling offline using org.apache.hadoop/* dependencies

Tags: scala, hadoop, sbt, ivy

got a lot of troubles compiling offline with sbt having dependencies on org.apache.hadoop packages.

A simple build.sbt:

```
name := "Test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-yarn-api" % "2.2.0"
```

works fine while online but gives following error when running offline, while the package is present in the ivy cache (under ~/ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/...):

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/martin/Dev/S/project
[info] Set current project to Test (in build file:/home/martin/Dev/S/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/martin/Dev/S/}s...
[info] Resolving org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0 ...
[warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/martin/.ivy2/local/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:2.2.0 (/home/martin/Dev/S/build.sbt#L15-16)
[warn]        +- test:test_2.10:1.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
    ...
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 26, 2015 2:46:58 PM
```

Adding the following resolver didn't help:

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("Local repo", file(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ivy2/cache")) (Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

It just adds

```
[warn] ==== Local repo: tried
[warn]   /home/martin/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
```

The files are present but named ivy-2.2.0.xml, not 2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml

So i tried adding

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("Local repo 2", file(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ivy2/cache")) ( Patterns("[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]") )
```

To force the naming convention but it then looks under

```
[warn] ==== Local repo 2: tried
[warn]   /home/martin/.ivy2/cache/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/ivy-2.2.0.xml
```

even when according to the sbt doc [organisation] should be org.apache.hadoop and not org/apache/hadoop

So finally as a last resort i added an ugly

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("Local hadoop cache", file(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ivy2/cache")) ( Patterns("org.apache.hadoop/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]") )
```

and there it found something, but still was not happy with it:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/martin/Dev/S/project
[info] Set current project to Test (in build file:/home/martin/Dev/S/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/martin/Dev/S/}s...
[info] Resolving org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0 ...
[warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn] xml parsing: ivy-2.2.0.xml.original:18:69: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
[warn] xml parsing: ivy-2.2.0.xml.original:19:11: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
[warn] xml parsing: ivy-2.2.0.xml.original:20:17: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
[warn] xml parsing: ivy-2.2.0.xml.original:21:14: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
[warn] xml parsing: ivy-2.2.0.xml.original:22:14: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
[warn] xml parsing: ivy-2.2.0.xml.original:24:17: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
[warn] xml parsing: ivy-2.2.0.xml.original:25:12: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
...
```

I'm out of clues about what to to try next. Building offline works fine for any other dependency i tried if i copy the .ivy2/cache/ directories to the offline machine. It's just a bunch of org.apache.hadoop dependencies that cause this problem. The structure and the files under .ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop look the same as the ones from the other dependencies that work well.

Adding

```
offline := true
```

didn't help either.

Using sbt 0.13.7

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed to be an sbt bug. I had same problems with **sbt 0.13.8** but they gone away with switching to **0.13.9-RC3** and cleaning `~/.ivy2`

Comment: Thanks !

While i don't have access to the original project that lead to the OP anymore, i just reproduced it and validated your solution.

The OP was with sbt 0.13.7 but i can confirm the problem still exists with 0.13.8 and is fixed with 0.13.9-RC3.

I didn't need to clean the ~/.ivy2 directory but i needed to clean the project's local target/ directory for offline build to work. Without cleaning it up only online builds worked, after cleanup on- and offline works. Still using the old ~/.ivy2

Comment: Not sure about `project/target` directory, may be I forgot that I've deleted it. Glad that it helps.

Comment: By the way the 0.13.9 release is officially out now and has been pushed to their package repositories.

Thanks again

Comment: I had a similar issue but with 0.13.12.
Simply deleting the offending cached libraries, e.g. ~/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop did the trick